# Which file is processed first, index.php, index.htm or index.html?

Tags: apache-2.2

In a Apache server, if a domain www.abc.com has index.php, index.htm and index.html, which files get processed first when I enter www.abc.com in the address bar? Is there a way to change the order? I know we can do it in IIS.

Answer (score 5):

The order is specified by the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Comment: any idea where would i change the directory index in cpanel

Comment: No, Apache configs are way too simple for me to fork out $500 a year for a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the entries in the `DirectoryIndex` directive determine which is looked at first.

Answer (score 1):

Look up ["DirectoryIndex"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html)

Answer (score -2):

Apache Server processed first **index.php then index.html and last index.htm.**
Priority wise:

1. index.php
2. index.html
3. index.htm

Comment: This is *wrong*. The order is configured. And it is actually configured by default differently on different distros.